# How to get gutters

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, columnsorting

I am new to twitter bootstrap trying to build my first website with it. I have a good template going. I ran into the issue that I don't know how to solve without applying css. I wanted to find out if it can be solved without css help.

I have a 12 column grid. I put in 3 images taking up 4 columns. I end up with a nice gutter on between all three images. I added three more images below the top 3 and end up with a nice gutter between them as well. Problem is that there is no gutter on top of the images. So the images in the top columns are touching the images in the bottom columns.

How do you get the nice gutter on top?

I thought if I put the bottom 3 images into a new row that would solve it but it didn't.

Here is my code

```
<div class="row">
        <h2>Featured Projects</h2>

        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <img src="images/puters.png" class="img-responsive" height="189" width="327" alt="computers">
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <img src="images/teacher.png" class="img-responsive" height="189" width="327" alt="teacher">
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <img src="images/student.png" class="img-responsive" height="189" width="327" alt="students">
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <img src="images/test.png" class="img-responsive" height="189" width="327" alt="students">
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <img src="images/puters.png" class="img-responsive" height="189" width="327" alt="computers">
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <img src="images/teacher.png" class="img-responsive" height="189" width="327" alt="teacher">
        </div>
    </div><!--END row-->
```

Comment: In Bootstrap, gutters are for columns only. I would stick with 3 images per `row` and add CSS to your rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Jamie** Hi there.
You could do it like this... add a class to a `row` that hold the second set of images.
This way your just adding one class and not one to each second row images.
I know you wanted not to use any css but this works for what you want to do.
Hope this helps.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Starter Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<style>
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.spacer {
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}    
.clear-top {
  margin-top: 25px;
}    
</style>

</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top ">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand " href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

<div class="container col-lg-12 spacer"></div>

<div class="container col-lg-12">

<div class="row">
        <h2>Featured Projects</h2>

        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/640/640/nature" class="img-responsive" alt="computers">
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/640/640/nature" class="img-responsive" alt="teacher">
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/640/640/nature" class="img-responsive" alt="students">
        </div>
</div><!--END row-->        
<div class="row clear-top">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/640/640/nature" class="img-responsive" alt="students">
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/640/640/nature" class="img-responsive" alt="computers">
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/640/640/nature" class="img-responsive" alt="teacher">
        </div>
</div><!--END row-->
        
</div><!-- /.container -->


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```